# Displace close points

Tags: qgis-3

I am making a map with some points of interest to be used on our webpages and presentations. Two of these points are so close that they are overlapping if I use big enough points to make them easily visble.

[image]

I want to keep those points in their right positions in the data set, but what would be the easiest way to displace one or both points slightly? The point displacement and point cloud options does not work for this (as far as I can see) since I need to have the points as two different symbol types and I want to have them in the right relative directions i.e. the green point slightly west of the blue point.

Using QGIS 3.24

Update: I tried to make a manual offset on the green symbol to move it 1 mm to the left. That gave me what I wanted, the problem was that that will mess up the legend as it also moves the symbol the same amount in the legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired effect by (ab)using the label background function.

A symbol is drawn at a given location and overlaps nearby symbol. It is difficult to offset them since the "nearby" distance is related to the map scale and there is no need to offset a lonely symbol.

Labels are automatically places close the original location and are displaced to avoid overlapping another label. It is therefore possible to use the desired symbol as a label, more precisely as the background of an almost empty label.

For the layer of interest - or a copy of it (not to mess the legend), use a single symbol with a size of 0.

Create a rule base label and create a rule for each symbol of interest. Set the filter accordingly.

[image]

Instruct to label several white spaces (`'     '`), with a background of type `marker` (or `svg`) then select the symbol of interest by clicking the down triangle / `configure symbol`

[image]

A placement `around point` should work

[image]

Here are the two points when zoomed out (I have added a dot at the original location for clarity)
[image]

and when zoomed-in

[image]